# NodeJS - MongoDB - Ajax multiple file upload and save path to DB not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm doing Ajax multiple `PDF` uploads to NodeJS server and saving the path to MongoDB `Book` Document.

The problem is When I upload multiple files for the first time, only one book path is getting saved to the MongoDB document, the other files are uploaded correctly which I can check in the `uploads` directory, but not getting saved to the document.

I know, the problem is something related to asynchronous process in NodeJS. But I don't know how to solve this.

Here is the code for uploading files and saving the path to MongoDB document.

```js
var express = require('express')
var formidable = require('formidable')
var Book = require('../models/book')
var router = express.Router()
var path = require('path')
var uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/../uploads/')
var uploadDir2 = path.join(__dirname, '/..')
var imageDir = path.join(__dirname, '/../uploads/images/')
var exec = require('child_process').exec

router.post('/api/upload', function (req, res, next) {
  var email = req.user.email
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
  form.multiples = true
  form.keepExtensions = true
  form.uploadDir = uploadDir

  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json({ error: err })
    if (Array.isArray(files.userBooks)) {
      files.userBooks.forEach(function (item, index) {
        // bookPath.push(item.path.split('LibreRead')[1])
        item = item.path.split('LibreRead')[1]
        saveBooks(item)
        getCover(item)
      })
    } else {
      var item = files.userBooks.path.split('LibreRead')[1]
      saveBooks(item)
      getCover(item)
    }

    function saveBooks (bookPath) {
      Book.find({email: req.user.email}, function (err, content) {
        if (err) console.error(err)
        var coverPath = '/uploads/images/' + bookPath.split('/uploads/').pop() + '-001-000.png'
        var list = [{bookPath: bookPath, coverPath: coverPath}]

        if (!content.length) {
          var b = new Book({email: email, list: [list]})
          return b.save(function (err, content) {
            if (err) return console.log(err)
            console.log(content)
          })
        } else {
          content[0].list.push(list)
          return content[0].save(function (err, content) {
            if (err) return console.error(err)
            console.log(content)
          })
        }
      })
    }

    function getCover (bookPath) {
      var cmd = 'pdfimages -p -png -f 1 -l 2 ' + uploadDir2 + bookPath + ' ' + imageDir + bookPath.split('/uploads/').pop()
      return exec(cmd, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) return console.error(err)
        console.log(stdout)
      })
    }

    res.redirect('/')
  })
  form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file) {
    const [fileName, fileExt] = file.name.split('.')
    file.path = path.join(uploadDir, `${fileName}_${new Date().getTime()}.${fileExt}`)
  })
})

module.exports = router
```

I think `forEach` loop is synchronous/blocking, but still only one file path is getting saved, the others are not present in MongoDB

Any help would be useful to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe is timing issue due to the you did not wait all your save process done before you response redirect.

You can solve this by using Promise (if your nodejs version support es6, or npm install bluebird)

```
router.post('/api/upload', function (req, res, next) {
    var email = req.user.email
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
    form.multiples = true
    form.keepExtensions = true
    form.uploadDir = uploadDir

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).json({ error: err })

        var promise;
        if (Array.isArray(files.userBooks)) {
            promise = Promise.all(files.userBooks.map(function (item, index) {
                // bookPath.push(item.path.split('LibreRead')[1])
                item = item.path.split('LibreRead')[1]
                return saveAndReturnCover(item)
            })).then(function(covers) {
                // do something with the results if you want to
            })
        } else {
            var item = files.userBooks.path.split('LibreRead')[1]
            promise = saveAndReturnCover(item)                
        }
        promise.then(function () {
            res.redirect('/')
        })

        function saveAndReturnCover(item) {
            return saveBooks(item).then(function () {
                return getCover(item)
            })
        }

        function saveBooks(bookPath) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                Book.find({ email: req.user.email }, function (err, content) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err)
                        return reject(err)
                    }
                    var coverPath = '/uploads/images/' + bookPath.split('/uploads/').pop() + '-001-000.png'
                    var list = [{ bookPath: bookPath, coverPath: coverPath }]

                    if (!content.length) {
                        var b = new Book({ email: email, list: [list] })
                        return b.save(function (err, content) { // no idea what .save will return
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err)
                                return reject(err)
                            }
                            console.log(content)
                            resolve(content)
                        })
                    } else {
                        content[0].list.push(list)
                        return content[0].save(function (err, content) { // no idea what .save will return
                            if (err) {
                                console.error(err)
                                return reject(err)
                            }
                            console.log(content)
                            resolve(content)
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        }

        function getCover(bookPath) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var cmd = 'pdfimages -p -png -f 1 -l 2 ' + uploadDir2 + bookPath + ' ' + imageDir + bookPath.split('/uploads/').pop()
                return exec(cmd, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err)
                        reject(err)
                    } 
                    console.log(stdout)
                    resolve(stdout)
                })
            })
        }        
    })
    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file) {
        const [fileName, fileExt] = file.name.split('.')
        file.path = path.join(uploadDir, `${fileName}_${new Date().getTime()}.${fileExt}`)
    })
})
```